# How to only print a summary Digital Metaphor's Report Builder

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I've got a simple report set up with a Header, Detail, Footer and a Summary band.  In the detail band there is a sub report. I would like to have the option to hide the detail of the report and only show the summary.

I've tried setting the Visible field to false, but that causes ReportBuilder to get stuck in the window before displaying the report. Are there any other ways to hide the detail band?

Comment: I don't have RB installed ay more but there is bound to be a way to do this.  Have you tried asking the vendors?

Comment: Have you tried setting the height of the detail band to 0 in the BeforePrint of the Summary?  Sometimes you have to do some trickery to get the summary calcs to work...